# How can I change the histogram label in x axis and add a trend line to the histogram

Tags: python, plotly

I am plotting a frequency histogram, and I want the x_axis to show the range of each bar, eg.[0-9],[10-19]... rather than 50, 100, 150, 200. I also want to add a trend line to this histogram like the example below. Please help!

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.histogram(df, x=data, color_discrete_sequence=['purple'])
fig.update_layout(bargap=0.01)
fig.show()
```

[image]

example:
[image]

Comment: See [this](https://plotly.com/python/distplot/#combined-statistical-representations-with-distplot-figure-factory). `df = px.data.tips();fig = ff.create_distplot([df['total_bill']], group_labels=['total_bill'], bin_size=5, show_curve=True, show_rug=False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can go back to basics and use **pandas** `cut()` and `value_counts()`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

SIZE = 5
df = px.data.tips()
df = (
    pd.cut(
        df["total_bill"],
        bins=np.arange(0, df["total_bill"].max() + SIZE, SIZE, dtype=int),
    )
    .value_counts()
    .sort_index()
    .reset_index()
    .assign(label=lambda d: d["index"].apply(lambda x: f"{x.left} to {x.right}"))
)
px.bar(df, x="label", y="total_bill", color_discrete_sequence=["purple"]).update_layout(
    bargap=0.01
).add_traces(
    px.line(df, x="label", y="total_bill").update_traces(line={"shape": "spline"}).data
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import seaborn as sns 

x = [100,300,200,500,400,300,100,700,1000,1200,3000,2000,2500,3500,4000,4500,5000,150]

sns.set_style('darkgrid')
 
sns.distplot(x)
```

Use the above code you will get a bell curve.
Install the seaborn before using the above code

use the below command

```
pip install seaborn
```